# bit c manipulation

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

This question's accepted answer shows how to set a bit in c: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

But it is not really said what 'x' is.

Is it counted from left to right or right to left ? Isn't that platform dependent anyway ?

Comment: The bit is counted starting from the least significant bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard doesn't say how you number the bits you shift. It says that a value will be twice as large for each position you shift it.

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 x 2<sup>E2</sup>, [...].

On most current machines, this means that `1 << x` will set bit number x in the value's representation. It formally doesn't say where that bit is stored.